# Отображение изменения параметра на форме в реальном времени WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, редактор, blend

Есть необходимость написать свой `CustomControl`.

Разобрался как его организовать и добавил параметр, для теста.

Создал привязку этого параметра к параметру определяющим скругление краев у **Border**.

Вроде бы и работает, но не обновляется в самом редакторе. То есть после выноса элемента на форму и изменения моего параметра, края как были так и остаются. Помогает только: собрать приложение и закрыть его. После этого скругление в редакторе отображается. Делаю привязку через контекстное меню параметра.

Может я что-то не то выбираю в дополнительных настройках или какой-то код автообновления нужен?

(Делаю всё в Blend)

```
public class APIButton : Button
{

    int _rad;
    public int rad
    {
        get { return _rad; }
        set { _rad = value;

        }
    }


    static APIButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(APIButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(APIButton)));
    }
}
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:APIButton}">
                <Border
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="{Binding rad, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:APIButton}}}" Background="#FFA65151" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство rad оно может использоваться только для чтения при биндинге в том виде как вы его описали, т.к. в settere  нет ничего что могло бы как-то оповестить Фреймворк об изменении данного свойства. Для Custom Control в данном случае нужно использовать DependenctyProperty 
rad переименовал в Rad поэтому шаблон с биндингом тоже не забудьте поменять

```
public class APIButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rad", typeof(int), typeof(APIButton));

    public int Rad
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(RadProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(RadProperty, value);
        }
    }


    static APIButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(APIButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(APIButton)));
    }
}
```